# NullPointerException encountered when sending javax.security.auth.Subject object over RMI

Tags: java, client-server, rmi, jaas, java-security

I am developing a client-server system where users uses RMI (over SSL) for authentication.

The client calls the LoginInf.login() method:

```
public interface LoginIntf extends Remote {    
    Subject login(String username, char[] password) throws RemoteException;    
}
```

And on the server, the LoginImpl.login() method is implemented as:

```
@Override
public Subject login(String username, char[] password) throws RemoteException {
    logger.debug("I'm going to authenticate:");
    logger.debug("   username: {}", username);
    logger.debug("   password: {}", String.valueOf(password));

    Subject userSubject = null;
    try {
        LoginContext lc = new LoginContext("AESLogin", new RemoteCallbackHandler(username, String.valueOf(password)));
        lc.login();
        userSubject = lc.getSubject();

        // debug
        Set<Principal> pSet = userSubject.getPrincipals();            
        pSet.stream().forEach((p) -> {
            logger.info(p.getName());
        });                        
    } catch (LoginException ex) {
        logger.warn(ex);
    }

    return userSubject;
}
```

However, when on the client side, after executing the LoginIntf.login() method, I get NullPointerException:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.security.auth.Subject$SecureSet.readObject(Subject.java:1341) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1900) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.access$300(ObjectInputStream.java:206) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$GetFieldImpl.readFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2164) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFields(ObjectInputStream.java:541) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.readObject(Subject.java:966) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1900) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.unmarshalValue(UnicastRef.java:326) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:175) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:227) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:179) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.login(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at tw.com.asanga.aes.ife.core.IFE_MainFrame.submit_ButtonActionPerformed(IFE_MainFrame.java:537) [classes/:?]
    at tw.com.asanga.aes.ife.core.IFE_MainFrame.access$100(IFE_MainFrame.java:32) [classes/:?]
    at tw.com.asanga.aes.ife.core.IFE_MainFrame$2.actionPerformed(IFE_MainFrame.java:180) [classes/:?]
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022) [?:1.8.0_66]
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348) [?:1.8.0_66]
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402) [?:1.8.0_66]
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259) [?:1.8.0_66]
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252) [?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535) [?:1.8.0_66]
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324) [?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300) [?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236) [?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891) [?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294) [?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713) [?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888) [?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525) [?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466) [?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280) [?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750) [?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713) [?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758) [?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97) [?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709) [?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703) [?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76) [?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86) [?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731) [?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729) [?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76) [?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728) [?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201) [?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116) [?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105) [?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101) [?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93) [?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82) [?:1.8.0_66]
```

I get the NPE even without storing the returned Subject object in a local variable and accessing it.

I can't figure out the cause of NPE.  I don't believe it's permission related as I'm in DEV phase and have granted AllPermission in my policy file:

```
grant {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

I know that javax.security.auth.Subject implements Serializable, so sending this over RMI shouldn't be an issue.

Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't like this design. The Subject should stay on the server side. You should use a remote session pattern for this.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion EJB.   Even though I solved my own problem, i.e. I can now send Subject from Server to Client, I am keen to explore your feedback.

Can you please help explain why Subject should only stay on the server side?

I am new to JAAS, and my reasoning for sending the Subject to client is so that later, when the user needs to logout, this can be done by constructing a LoginContext object with the received Subject, and subsequently calling LoginContext.logout().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason for the NPE is because my implementation of the Principal object only resided on the Server codebase.